# Asynchronous network interface status check

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

On Mac OS X, is there a way to get asynchronous notification when the network interface (en0, en1) status changes, such as network interface is active, inactive etc?

Instead of polling for the status, i would like to know is there a way to get asynchronous notification, so that whenever there is a change, notification is fired and app can handle it.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what changes in the network state you want to be informed of (e.g. do you just want to know when you gain or lose a network connection, or do you want to know things like if you've switched WiFi networks or some more esoteric detail like that), and if you provide more details about that I can provide a better answer, **but generally speaking I reckon you want to use the** `SystemConfiguration` **framework, specifically probably the** `SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h` **APIs** (described in Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachability-g7d)).

Even more specifically than that, I think `SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack` is the type of callback function you want to use. [This here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachabilitycallback) is the Apple documentation for it.

Finally, to set up that callback, I mean first you have to write your callback function, but to "register" it so SystemConfiguration will use it to call you back when your network status changes, use this guy: `SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(_:_:_:)` described in official Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1514903-scnetworkreachabilitysetcallback).

Hope this helps and if you want more specific help just add some more specifics to your question :)

Answer (score -3):

Check the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk). It is for the iOS SDK but the SystemConfigration framework mentioned is available on Mac OSX too.

Comment: this answer is for checking the connectivity, not catching *network interface updates*